# Where to save markers lng and lat to my app to add them to map at runtime?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-sqlite, google-maps-markers

I have about 60 `Markers` for about 20 different locations in text files on my lap.
I also have a `string-array` contains the names of the locations displayed on `RecyclerView` when a location is clicked a map is opened at that location with the given `Markers` added.
My question is where to save the lng,lat of these `Markers` so I can get them at runtime when needed.

**EDIT:** Database is my last choice, as I am new with it and I have little time.I hope there is a way to save these values to xml arrays.

Comment: Try to use HashMap with key are your location name and value are LatLang.

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in database along with the names so that you can retrieve later easily.

```
    public class CustomDataItem {
    String var1;

    public CustomDataItem(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    public String getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }

    public void setVar1(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think database is my last choice, as time is important.I hope there is a way to save them in xml arrays.

Comment: Database is the last and best choice.Or else you can create a custom datatype and create an ArrayList of that type so that you can retrieve the values using simple getter and setter methods.

Comment: That was my choice, but the question still how to save these values to my project and how to get them back when I need them.

Comment: See my edited answer.You can call the set method for setting your required value and can use get method to retrieve wherever required.

Comment: Create an ArrayList of this custom type and use it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to store it in your SQLite database. Then you can use a cursor to retrieve the all the data at runtime.
For saving time there are a lot of resources on Git hub which you can use. Look up for BoD content provider to quickly save/retrieve your data.